# Is it possible to get notified if the currently playing song on Spotify changes

Tags: python, django, networking, spotify

I need to update a screen in my app if the playing song changes, but I don't want to send http requests to the Spotify API every x amount of seconds.

I looked into Websockets and Long Polling but spotify doesnt offer any of that. I need to make the request on my Django server and send it to the client using websockets, this part is working and the UI is already built but I can't find an efficient solution to my problem.

Comment: Can you pull the song duration from duration_ms (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-audio-features) and only make another request when that time has expired?

Comment: I thought of that already, but if the user skips a song he would have to wait at least a few seconds until the app updates, but thank you for your comment